# TypeError: echo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, discord.py

There is a command in my bot called `echo` and when I'm trying to call it I get some error. I don't know how to fix it.

```py
@commands.command()
async def echo(ctx, *,args):
    if ctx.author.id in [my id here]:
        await ctx.send(args)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("U cant use that :)")
```

Here is the log:

```
Private message > !echo now?
Ignoring exception in command echo:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: echo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: echo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Comment: What is the actual value of `*args` in the function call?

Comment: it should contain all symbols after command

Comment: I see that you are trying to check wether its you who is using the command. Use [```Bot.is_owner```](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.is_owner)

Comment: It's not clear from the code what type of object `ctx` is, but the function accepts only a single positional argument, and then (strictly) a set of keyword arguments. If  `args` is a tuple or list of length `n` > 1, for example, then in the function call `*args` would be unpacked into `n` positional arguments which is not allowed.

Comment: so how can i make it in more correct way ?

Comment: It depends on how you want to design the function and the data structures that you want to pass to it. For instance, if you want to pass an arbitrary number of positional arguments followed by an arbitrary number of keyword arguments, you could try `def echo(*args, **kwargs)`. If you have a more definite number in mind, you could use position-only or keyword-only parameters or a combination thereof. (The last part is only available in Python 3.8 or higher.)

Comment: if i use this i need to change code down but to what

Comment: Is this a class method and possibly needs a self parameter before ctx?

Comment: it was fine until i moved it to class so idk

Answer (score 0):

use `*args` instead of `*,args`. for example:

```
@commands.command()
async def echo(ctx, *args):
    if ctx.author.id in [my id here]:
        await ctx.send(args)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("U cant use that :)")
```

Comment: if i use this it gives back ``('now',)``

Answer (score 0):

Tou should try using “self” due to it being inside a [cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html) (Assuming). And yes, it is `ctx, *, args`
It would look something like this:

```
@commands.command()
async def echo(self, ctx, *, args):
    if ctx.author.id in [my id here]:
        await ctx.send(args)
        await ctx.message.delete()
    else:
        await ctx.send("You can't use that :)")
```

By the way, what the code would do is send the message and delete it immediately after, you might want to swap the `send` and the `delete`. Let me know if this helped!